# echoed password input field shows as text

Tags: php, html, apache, passwords

Im trying to make a simple registration form using php with XAMPP(Apache and MYSQL).I'm currently having a problem with my password field which is currently displaying it's input as clear text, instead of hiding it from view.

```
?php
$regfields=array("remail"=>"Email","remail2"=>"Re-enter     Email","rusername"=>"Username","rpassword"=>"Password","rpassword2"=>"Re-enter Password","rbiz"=>"BizName","rdesc"=>"Desc");
?>

<html>
<body>
<h3>Registration</h3>
<form action="Login.php" name="RegisterForm" method="post" >
<table border="0">

<?php

if(isset($errormsg))
{
    echo"$errormsg";
}

foreach($regfields as $field=>$value)
{

    if($field!=="rdesc")
    {
        echo"<tr>";
        echo"<td>";
        echo"<label for='$field'>$value: </label>";
        echo"</td>";
        echo"<td>";
        echo"<input type='text' name='$field' size='40' maxlength='50' />    </td></tr>";

    }
    else if($field=="remail"||$field=="remail2")
    {
        echo"<tr>";
        echo"<td>";
        echo"<label for='$field'>$value: </label>";
        echo"</td>";
        echo"<td>";
        echo"<input type='text' name='$field' size='40' maxlength='50' /></td></tr>";

    }
    else if($field=="rpassword"||$field=="rpassword2")
    {
        echo"<tr>";
        echo"<td>";
        echo"<label for='$field'>$value: </label>";
        echo"</td>";
        echo"<td>";
        echo"<input type='password' name='$field' size='40' maxlength='50' /></td></tr>";

    }
    else
    {
        echo"<tr>";
        echo"<td>";
        echo"<label for=$field>$value: </label>";
        echo"</td>";
        echo"<td>";
        echo"<input type='text' name='$field' size='300' maxlength='300' style='width:400px;height:100px; \n'/>";
        echo"</td>";
        echo"</tr>";
    }
}

?>
</form>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="Button" value="Register" />
</body>
</html>
```

I suspect my problem stems from this line

```
echo"<input type='password' name='$field' size='40' maxlength='50' /></td></tr>";
```

where the input type is not registering due to the single quotes used, instead of double quotes causing the input type to be interpreted literally and not being used as a value?

I would appreciate any input on this.
Thanks!

Comment: Is this being shown in the input as plain text or after submission..?

Comment: your closing form tag before table and submit is outside form. How will this work?

Comment: Try escaping this line `echo"<input type='password' name='$field'` with `\"` chars., see what that gives.

Comment: @Fred There is no need to escape single quotes within a double quote echo.. The best you could do with escape is to have `'".$field."'`

Comment: Just tested and it worked fine for me?

Comment: @DarylGill I meant `type=\"password\" etc.` instead of `type='password'`.

Comment: @Fred You should have made that clearer

Comment: @rahulRaj The submit button is working as i'm sent to Login.php upon clicking the submit button.

Comment: I Checked your code, on phpFiddle, the Password field is rendered as `type='text'` check your logi for if else

Comment: @Fred Stangely enough, nothing visible seems to have changed/happened after escaping type=\'password\'

Comment: @Ken Not `type=\'password\'` but `type=\"password\"`

Comment: @Fred, yep tried that too, nothing seems to have changed.

Comment: @Ken May be nothing, but in your shown code, you're missing your `<` on top, shows as `?php`. Maybe just a typo?

Comment: @Fred, Rab Nawaz figured out the problem, you can refer to his answer below ;) Thanks a bunch for your input though!

Comment: @Ken No problemo. Glad things worked out for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ohhh check this out

below code is Executed All the time, except when the field is  `rdesc`.   So correct your code by removing `!` from `if($field!=="rdesc")`

```
  if($field!=="rdesc")
    {
        echo"<tr>";
        echo"<td>";
        echo"<label for='$field'>$value: </label>";
        echo"</td>";
        echo"<td>";
        echo"<input type='text' name='$field' size='40' maxlength='50' />    </td></tr>";

    }
```

Comment: Arghhhh it was such a glaring mistake! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you find the usage of single and double quotes confusing, try this

```
<?php
else if($field=="rpassword"||$field=="rpassword2")
    {?>

<tr>
    <td>
        <label for="<?php echo $field?>"><?php echo $value?>: </label>
        </td>
        <td>
        <input type="password" name="<?php echo $field?>" size='40' maxlength='50' /></td></tr>
<?php
    }?>
```

Its not considered as a good practie to echo `HTML` inside `PHP`